# Video Capture Devices available in RDP (mstsc) but not Virtual Machine Connection (vmconnect)?

Tags: hyper-v, remote-desktop, windows-10, mstsc

I'm trying to pass my webcam through to a Hyper-V VM using Virtual Machine Connection (vmconnect). In the "Local Devices and resources" settings, I do not have the ability to do this:

[image: vmconnect local devices and resources]

However using Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc) with the same host & guest, I am able to pass through the webcam: [image: mstsc local devices and resources]

My understanding is that vmconnect uses the same libraries as mstsc. I've checked the versions of both and they're both the same (10.0.18362.1). Both client and server are the same - Windows 10 1909.

Is there a setting or option I'm missing or is this just not available in vmconnect?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I have managed to get the RemoteFX option to show up in VMConnect.exe twice ever, and I do not know what conditions are required for this to happen. mstsc, it shows always, but I cannot use mstsc for this VM due to security reasons.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Run vmconnect.exe as admin.

**OR**

If you do not want to run as admin then there is a setting for this.
Select admin and users here.
[image: gpedit.msc here you have to update]

Then move to second and third setting.
[image: Second and Third Setting]

Then run `gpupdate /force`. once completed, reboot the computer and try again.